# How do I assign a user multiple passwords

Tags: python

I have a script that is taking usernames and passwords from two txt files. My problem is how do I assign each user to try all the passwords in the list. My script looks like this so far.

```
user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')

for file1, file2 in zip (user, password):
    print ('{0}\t{1}'.format(file1.strip(), file2.strip()))
```

This is what I get for my output:

```
User0@mymail.com    Password1
User1@mymail.com    Password2
User2@mymail.com    Password3
User3@mymail.com    Password4
User4@mymail.com    Password5
User5@mymail.com    Password6
User6@mymail.com    Password7
User7@mymail.com    Password8
User8@mymail.com    Password9
User9@mymail.com    Password10
```

This is what I am trying to achive :

```
User0@mymail.com "Password1
                  Password2
                  Password3
                  Password4
                  Password5
                  Password6
                  Password7
                  Password8
                  Password9
                  Password10"

User1@mymail.com "Password1
                  Password2
                  Password3
                  Password4
                  Password5
                  Password6
                  Password7
                  Password8
                  Password9
                  Password10"
```

And goes back gets user 2 and gets all 10 passwords.

Comment: `How do I assign each user to try all the passwords`. In proper english this means what, exactly?

Comment: How do I get User0@mymail.com to use all the 10 passwords. Then once its done goes to the next user 2 to use all the 10 passwords up to the last user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, byt if you want each user to be followed by all passwords. then put all passwords in one line and iterate over users and then append that line.

something like:

```
lineWithAllPasswords = ','.join(password,'\n')

for user in users:
    print (user + '\t' + lineWithAllPasswords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the Question above. Each user loops the password.txt file.

```
user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')
pa = '\n'.join(password)

for users in user:
    print pa + users
```